# Finding smaller number of two numbers using HCF and LCM

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Two numbers have $HCF=100$ and $LCM=3000$. Find the smaller of the two numbers if both numbers are more than $100$.

Comment: Hint : The product of two numbers is the product of their LCM and HCF. Therefore looking at factors of the product of $100$ and $3000$ which are greater than $100$ would be useful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The product is $300,000$ and both numbers are divisible by $100$ and can be divided by $3,000.$ 
Let the numbers be $100m$ and $100n,$ $m$ and $n$ being integers then by product $mn = 30$ and hence $m,n$ can be $1,30; 2,15; 3,10; 5,6$ but the first case is not possible hence smaller number can be $200, 300, 500$